# Thunderbird does not delete mails on the server

Tags: email

I have Thunderbird version 24.4.0 and Ubuntu 14.04 - all fresh installed.
when mails are downloaded, they remain on the server. I found no settings in the Thunderbird where to tell him to delete the mails on the server after download them localy.
do you know where it is ?

Comment: Are you using pop or imap? What mail server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into server settings, and un-check **Leave message on server**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is probably screenshot from different thunderbird release, as I do not have such option there

Comment: @user262898, either you aren't seeing it, or you aren't using pop.  If you are using IMAP, then the point of that protocol is to keep the mail on the server rather than download them locally.

Comment: It is 24.4.0 see added image in my answer.  And as psusi stated.  Since IMAP allows users to access email from anything/anywhere, hence the email lives on the server.

Comment: I wrongly configured the incoming server . it must be POP, then it's configurable. thanks.